# How are typescript imports resolved to find libraries in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an Angular 2.4 app with typescript.
With my first try with Angular 1 I never pushed node modules up to a testing environment. Just pushed the compiled code. But with Angular 2.4, typescript is "importing" these libraries from node modules. Hence when I push my bundled app to test environment it is failing because the node modules are missing.

Do I have to push the node modules to test environment in order to make it work?
How are you deploying your angular 2 app to a non local environment.

Thank you!

Comment: A correctly bundled app has all the javascript code in the javascript file(s) it needs to run. The browser has no concept of imports and of course no way to access a node_modules directory on disk, nor should it. Raw ES6 `import` statements do not exist in bundled code.

Comment: It depends, are you using System.js or some other module loader/bundler?

Comment: Thanks Andy Ray! it makes sense. But the index.html file (as given in the seed project) refers to some js files, like shim.min.js, zone.js, system.src.js directly from node modules. How would these get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't import any module your application from node_modules. Define node_modules path in systemjs.config.js then use your application. Sample systemjs.config.js file and use node_modules component in any component has below codes.

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Template/js/kpxl/app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            'primeng': 'npm:primeng',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**any component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import { LazyLoadEvent, Button, Dialog } from 'primeng/primeng'

@Component({
    selector: 'error-log',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/Settings/ErrorLog.html'
})
export class ErrorLog implements OnInit {

}
```